# Boolean won't initialize after an if statement and still coming as false when called from a different class in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make a text based game. I am putting somethings I have learned to practice.

*When you read about my problem you will probably be confused. My problem contains methods that have yet not been explained in what they do. This is so it does not get too confusing. Each piece of code will have a description of what methods it has and what they do.*

**My problem:** I have a class named *CharStartingPoint*, this class is the main starting point to my game. Inside the class I call the *choose();* method which is a method from class *CharObe* then the *settingNPC();* and *bbs();* methods are called, both of those methods are from *CharWosna* class. The *bbs();* method just returns a boolean referenced, player1HasShieldBo, and prints out string player1HasShield. (player1HasShield and player1HasShieldBo are from class *CharObe* and player2HasShieldBo is from class *CharWosna*). When *choose();* is called, and the player types yes to the question "Do you have a shield?", if the if statement sees if the user typed yes it will call a method named *setPlayerShieldTrue(boolean HasSield);* and pass player1HasShieldBo which sets player1HasShieldBo = true. If I type                     System.out.println(player1.player1HasShieldBo); and
        System.out.println(player1.player1HasShield); from class CharStartingPoint, it prints out true and yes. Class CharStartingPoint has no problem accessing CharObe's variables. When CharWosna class tries accessing CharObe's variable, CharWosna can access them but they are not initialized, WHY????? for this problem to be seen, when method *settingNPC();* is called, player2HasShieldBo is set to true if player2HasShieldBo is true. In this case player2HasShieldBo is set to false because class CharWosna accessed player1HasShieldBo from class CharObe, but it is not initialized although it had been initialized earlier. String player1HasShield prints out null when accessed from class CharWosna. WHY????

*player1 is of type CharObe and has a constructor of CharObe.*
*player2 is of type CharWosna and has a constructor of CharWosna.*

**Here is my code by chunks and explained**

**Class CharObe:**

**The *choose();* method:** The choose method asks the user if they have a shield or not. If the user types no to the question, do you have a shield? the boolean *player1HasShieldBo* is set to false. If the user types yes, then inside the if statement the *setPlayerShieldTrue();* method is called.

**The *setPlayerShieldTrue(boolean HasSield);* method:** this method takes in a boolean. Inside this boolean the local variable *HasSield* is set to true which then is assigned to *player1HasShieldBo*.

**The *returnIfHasShield();* method:** this method just returns boolean *player1HasShieldBo*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CharObe implements CharInterface {

  String player1HasShield;
  boolean player1HasShieldBo = false;
  int player1ShieldLevel;
  int player1ShieldHealth;
  boolean valid = false;
  Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);

  public void choose(){

      do{
          //asking the user if they have a shield or not
          System.out.println("\ndo you have a shield? (if yes only type" + 
                                 "'yes' if no type 'no')");
          System.out.print("Shield? yes or no? > ");
          if(keyBoard.hasNext()){
            player1HasShield = keyBoard.next();

              if(player1HasShield.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
                System.out.println("You have a SHIELD!!!");
                setPlayerShieldTrue(player1HasShieldBo);

                  System.out.println("What is your shield Level? (Only" + 
                                            "numbers 1-5)");

                  do{
                  System.out.print("Shield level > ");
                  if(keyBoard.hasNextInt()){
                      player1ShieldLevel = keyBoard.nextInt();

                     if(player1ShieldLevel >= 1 && player1ShieldLevel <= 5){
                          valid = false;

                      }else{
                          System.out.println("PLEASE only numbers from 1-" +
                                            " 5");
                          valid = true;

                      }
                  }else{
                      System.out.println("Only numbers are valid");
                      keyBoard.next();
                      valid = true;

                  }

                  }while(valid);



              }else{
                  System.out.println("You did not type 'yes'"
                          + " now you dont have a shield...");
                  player1ShieldLevel = 0;
                  valid = false;

              }

          }

      }while(valid);

      if(player1HasShieldBo){
          switch(player1ShieldLevel){
          case 1:   player1ShieldHealth = 5;    break;
          case 2:   player1ShieldHealth = 7;    break;
          case 3:   player1ShieldHealth = 15;   break;
          case 4:   player1ShieldHealth = 20;   break;
          case 5:   player1ShieldHealth = 30;   break;

          }

      }else{
          player1ShieldHealth = 0;
      }

      if(player1HasShieldBo){
      System.out.println(
              "\nPlayer1's shield level: "+ player1ShieldLevel +
              "\nplayer1's shield HP: " + player1ShieldHealth);
      }else{
          System.out.println(
              "\nPlayer1's shield level: "+ player1ShieldLevel +
              "\nplayer1's damage: " + player1Damage);
      }

      System.out.println("\nSetting player2's variables...");


  }

  public void setPlayerShieldTrue(boolean HasSield){
      HasSield = true;
      player1HasShieldBo = HasSield;
  }


  public boolean returnIfHasShield(){
          return player1HasShieldBo;
  }

}
```

**Method *settingNPC();***, this method sets boolean player2HasShieldBo = true if what is returned from method *returnIfHasShield();* is true. If what is returned is not true then player2HasShield will not be initialized and will stay false. That is the problem, although what is returned from *returnIfHasShield();* is player1HasShieldBo equaled to true, it will always returns false when access by CharWosna class.

**Method *bbs();***, this method prints out player1HasShieldBo and player1HasShield which come out to false and null because they are not initialized altough they had been earlier, why does this happen?

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CharWosna implements CharInterface{

  //player2 variables
  boolean player2HasShieldBo = true;
  int player2ShieldLevel;
  int player2ShieldHealth;

  CharObe toGet = new CharObe();    



  public void settingNPC(){

      if(toGet.returnIfHasShield()){
          player2HasShieldBo = true;

          player2ShieldLevel = toGet.player1ShieldLevel;
          player2ShieldHealth = toGet.player1ShieldHealth;

          System.out.println("Wosna's shield level: " + player2ShieldLevel +
                  "\nWosna's shield health: " + player2ShieldHealth
                  );


      }else{
          player2ShieldHealth = 0;
            System.out.println("To have a fair fight, Wosna, like you, will"  
                 + "not have a shield.");

      }

  }

  public void bbs(){
      System.out.println(toGet.player1HasShieldBo + " " + 
                       toGet.player1HasShield);
  }
}
```

**Class CharStarting point**, this class calls all methods

I found out the reason that CharObe's variable are initialized and can be accessed nicely in this class, it's because this class calls the *choose();* method.

```
public class CharStartingPoint {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Welcome! Fellow traveler.");
      System.out.println("please input proper information in order to" 
        + procceed to fight.\n");

      CharObe player1 = new CharObe();  
      CharWosna player2 = new CharWosna();

      player1.choose();
      player2.settingNPC();
      player2.bbs();
      System.out.println(player1.player1HasShieldBo);
      System.out.println(player1.player1HasShield);

    } 

}
```

**Interface CharInterface**, this is not yet used.

```
public interface CharInterface {
  int hurt(int curHealth, int hurting);
  int damage(int hitDamage);
  int shield(int shieldHealth, int shielLevel);

}
```

*Another problem is when i create an object in class CharObe, it straight up gives me a java.lang.StackOverflowError, why is that. *

**I dont know why I have all these problems. I may just have somethings that are very simple that have been messing up my program, I dont know.**

**Things I have tried**
-directly accessing the boolean player1HasShieldBo from class CharWosna
-creating another boolean having it have the value of player1HasShieldBo(when player1HasShieldBo equaled to true)
                                                                                       -initializing player1HasShieldBo from class CharObe (did not turn out as wanted, it always equaled true)

**if you want to see all my code here it is.**

**insterface**

```
public interface CharInterface {

  int hurt(int curHealth, int hurting);
  int damage(int hitDamage);
  int shield(int shieldHealth, int shielLevel);

}
```

**class CharStartingPoint**

```
public class CharStartingPoint {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Welcome! Fellow traveler.");
      System.out.println("please input proper information in order to" 
                + " procceed to fight.\n");

      CharObe player1 = new CharObe();  
      CharWosna player2 = new CharWosna();

      player1.choose();
      player2.settingNPC();
      player2.bbs();
      System.out.println(player1.player1HasShieldBo);
      System.out.println(player1.player1HasShield);

  } 

}
```

**class CharObe**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CharObe implements CharInterface {

  int player1Level;
  int player1Damage;
  int player1Health;
  String player1HasShield;
  boolean player1HasShieldBo = false;
  int player1ShieldLevel;
  int player1ShieldHealth;
  boolean valid = false;
  Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner(System.in);

  CharObe f = new CharObe();

  //Letting the user pick the players level and whether it has a shield or 
  not.
  public void choose(){
      System.out.println("what is Your player level? (number from 1-20)");

      do{

          //asking user for the level of their player
          System.out.print("Enter level here > ");
          if(keyBoard.hasNextInt()){
              player1Level = keyBoard.nextInt();

              if(player1Level >= 1 && player1Level <= 20){
                valid = false;

            }else{
                System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 20!");
                valid = true;

            }

          }else{
              System.out.println("Only numbers are valid");
              keyBoard.next();
              valid = true;

          }

      }while(valid);


      do{
          //asking the user if they have a shield or not
          System.out.println("\ndo you have a shield? (if yes only type" + 
                          "'yes' if no type 'no')");
          System.out.print("Shield? yes or no? > ");
          if(keyBoard.hasNext()){
              player1HasShield = keyBoard.next();

              if(player1HasShield.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
                  System.out.println("You have a SHIELD!!!");
                  setPlayerShieldTrue(player1HasShieldBo);


                  System.out.println("What is your shield Level? (Only" + 
                                     "numbers 1-5)");
                  do{
                  System.out.print("Shield level > ");
                  if(keyBoard.hasNextInt()){
                      player1ShieldLevel = keyBoard.nextInt();

                     if(player1ShieldLevel >= 1 && player1ShieldLevel <= 5){
                         valid = false;

                      }else{
                         System.out.println("PLEASE only numbers from 1-5");
                         valid = true;

                      }
                  }else{
                      System.out.println("Only numbers are valid");
                      keyBoard.next();
                      valid = true;

                  }

                  }while(valid);


              }else{
                  System.out.println("You did not type 'yes'"
                          + " now you dont have a shield...");
                  player1ShieldLevel = 0;
                  valid = false;

              }

          }

      }while(valid);

      switch(player1Level){
      case 1: player1Health = 100; player1Damage = 10;  break;
      case 2: player1Health = 105; player1Damage = 11;  break;
      case 3: player1Health = 110; player1Damage = 12;  break;
      case 4: player1Health = 80;   player1Damage = 20;     break;
      case 5:   player1Health = 100; player1Damage = 15;    break;
      case 6:   player1Health = 150; player1Damage = 5;     break;
      case 7:   player1Health = 115; player1Damage = 17;    break;
      case 8:   player1Health = 130; player1Damage = 20;    break;
      case 9:   player1Health = 135; player1Damage = 15;    break;
      case 10: player1Health = 140; player1Damage = 23; break;
      case 11: player1Health = 160; player1Damage = 17; break;
      case 12: player1Health = 150; player1Damage = 28; break;
      case 13: player1Health = 180; player1Damage = 15; break;
      case 14: player1Health = 155; player1Damage = 30; break;
      case 15: player1Health = 115; player1Damage = 40; break;
      case 16: player1Health = 200; player1Damage = 20; break;
      case 17: player1Health = 250; player1Damage = 35; break;
      case 18: player1Health = 1000; player1Damage = 67;    break;
      case 19: player1Health = 550; player1Damage = 130;    break;
      case 20: player1Health = 9999; player1Damage = 479;   break;

      }

      if(player1HasShieldBo){
          switch(player1ShieldLevel){
          case 1:   player1ShieldHealth = 5;    break;
          case 2:   player1ShieldHealth = 7;    break;
          case 3:   player1ShieldHealth = 15;   break;
          case 4:   player1ShieldHealth = 20;   break;
          case 5:   player1ShieldHealth = 30;   break;

        }


      }else{
          player1ShieldHealth = 0;
      }

      if(player1HasShieldBo){
      System.out.println(
              "\nPlayer1's level: " + player1Level +
              "\nPlayer1's Health: " + player1Health + 
              "\nplayer1's damage: " + player1Damage +
              "\nPlayer1's shield level: "+ player1ShieldLevel +
              "\nplayer1's shield HP: " + player1ShieldHealth);
      }else{
          System.out.println(
              "\nPlayer1's level: " + player1Level +
              "\nPlayer1's Health: " + player1Health +
              "\nPlayer1's shield level: "+ player1ShieldLevel +
              "\nplayer1's damage: " + player1Damage);
      }

      System.out.println("\nSetting player2's variables...");


  }

  public void setPlayerShieldTrue(boolean HasSield){
      HasSield = true;
      player1HasShieldBo = HasSield;
  }


  public boolean returnIfHasShield(){
          return player1HasShieldBo;
  }


  @Override
  public int hurt(int curHealth, int hurting) {

      return curHealth;
  }

  @Override
  public int damage(int hitDamage) {

      return hitDamage;
  }

  @Override
  public int shield(int shieldHealth, int shielLevel) {

      return 0;
  }


}
```

**class CharWosna**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class CharWosna implements CharInterface{

  //player2 variables
  int player2Level;
  int[] player2Damage = {15, 45, 67, 100, 5, 25, 1000};//array
  int player2Health[] = {100, 50, 1000, 550, 250, 99, 600};//array
  boolean player2HasShieldBo = true;
  int player2ShieldLevel;
  int player2ShieldHealth;

  //CharObe object created for acquiring CharObe's variables in that class 
  CharObe toGet = new CharObe();
  //ran is going to be used to access damage and health randomly 
  Random ran = new Random();


  public void settingNPC(){
      //LEVEL, HEALTH, and DAMAGE//

      player2Level = ran.nextInt(6) + 1;

      System.out.println("\n> Wosna's stats <");
      System.out.println(
              "\nWosna's level: " + player2Level +
              "\nWosna's health: " + player2Health[player2Level] +
              "\nWosna's damage: " + player2Damage[player2Level] 
              );

      if(toGet.returnIfHasShield()){
          player2HasShieldBo = true;

          player2ShieldLevel = toGet.player1ShieldLevel;
          player2ShieldHealth = toGet.player1ShieldHealth;

          System.out.println("Wosna's shield level: " + player2ShieldLevel +
                  "\nWosna's shield health: " + player2ShieldHealth
                  );


      }else{
          player2ShieldHealth = 0;
          System.out.println("To have a fair fight, Wosna, like you, will" +
                     "not have a shield.");

    }
  }
  public void bbs(){
      System.out.println(toGet.player1HasShieldBo + " " + 
                    toGet.player1HasShield);
  }

  @Override
  public int hurt(int curHealth, int hurting) {

      return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public int damage(int hitDamage) {

      return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public int shield(int shieldHealth, int shielLevel) {

      return 0;
  }

}
```

**Thank you**

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mcve], providing a MCVE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, Your code will work for setting the boolean. But you have some mistakes.

The stackOverflow is caused since you create a object of CharObe within the same class as a attribute. So for creating a CharObe object it needs to create a CharObe and so on...

the culprit line: on CharObe class

```
CharObe f = new CharObe();//remove this
```

Second thing, you cant just create an object of CharObe in CharWosna just to read the attributes.

This code is culprit too:

```
//CharObe object created for acquiring CharObe's variables in that class 
CharObe toGet = new CharObe();
```

Instead try passing the player1 object when creating player2 in the constructor.

like this in CharWonsa:

```
//CharObe object created for acquiring CharObe's variables in that class 
CharObe toGet;

public CharWosna(CharObe obe) {
  toGet=obe;
}
```

And finally in the class CharStartingPoint, create objects like this:

```
CharObe player1 = new CharObe();  
CharWosna player2 = new CharWosna(player1);
```

Another better way is that you maintain a GameContext class seperately and have all the necessary data like players there, and access from there.

You're welcome. Next time be precise with what you ask.

Comment: OH MY GOD!! thank you. I have been stuck with this problem for about a week and 1/2. Thank you.!!